# Undefined error in node.js but console.log works on the same line

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, undefined

I am new to node.js and this is my situation, I run 3 functions using async and then get the results and try to render a page which uses handlebars. I get an error on:

```
"avatar":data.avatar,
```

It says that data is undefined, but if I do `console.log(data.avatar)` the data is printed but it throws an error at the same `console.log` line saying

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatar' of null

Now the crazy thing is that if I comment out the `"tweets": tweets` or if I don't use the "tweets" field in handlebars page it works without any error!

```
app.get('/user/:user', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next){
var username = req.params.user;

var data = {};
var tweets = {};

async.series([
    function(callback){
        Tweet.find({ $or : [{"username":username}, {"retweeted_by":username}] }).sort({"created_at":-1}).exec(function(err, posts){
            if (err) res.redirect('/');

            tweets = posts;
            callback();
        });
    }, 
    function(callback){
         User.findOne({"username":username}).exec(function(err, user){
            if (err) res.redirect('/');

            data = user;
            callback();
         });
    },
    function(callback){
        User.findOne({ $and: [{"username":req.user.username}, {"follows": {"username":username}}] }).exec(function(err, foll){
            if (foll){
                if (foll.follows.length > 0)
                    data.do_we_follow = true;
            }

            callback();
        });
    }
], function(err, results){

    console.log(data.avatar);
       return  res.render('user', {
                "user":username, 
                "avatar":data.avatar,
                "cover":data.cover,  
                "numOfPosts":tweets.length, 
                "numOfFollowing":data.numOfFollowing,  
                "following":data.do_we_follow, 
                "username":req.user.username, 
                "myavatar":req.user.avatar, 
                "tweets": tweets
            });  
});
```

Comment: Do a `console.log` of your `user` in the `User.findOne` callback, and make sure data is being set to what you want it to. It appears data is being set to null

Comment: I did console.log(user.avatar) and  it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatar' of null" but the  data.avatar is passed to handlebars.

Comment: I did log(data) and got all the data I want but log(data) was called twice and the second time it was null